# 'Not in gzip format" error when decompressing gzip inputstream in java

Tags: java, gzip, compression

My code is attempting to decompress an input stream read from a gzipped file.

Here is the code snippet:

```
   InputStream is = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(fcontents.getBytes()));
```

The file itself is fine:

```
$cat storefront3.gz  | gunzip
180028796
80026920
180028796
180026921
8002790180
800001
1800002
1800007
800008
800009
```

The data read in prior to the top code snippet via FileInputStream sure looks like gzip stuff (note the original file was storefront3.tsv):

```
��[�Rstorefront3.tsvu���0k{)�?�/FBģ��Y'��Q�a���s~���}6���d�{2+���O���D�m~�O��
```

But get the following:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Not in GZIP format
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readHeader(GZIPInputStream.java:141)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:56)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:65)
```

Here is a hex dump of the .gz file

```
23:40:44/storefronts:72 $od -cx  storefront3.gz
0000000  037 213  \b  \b 201   [ 347   R  \0 003   s   t   o   r   e   f
             8b1f    0808    5b81    52e7    0300    7473    726f    6665
0000020    r   o   n   t   3   .   t   s   v  \0   u 212 273 025 200   0
             6f72    746e    2e33    7374    0076    8a75    15bb    3080
0000040   \f 003   k   { 032   ) 200   ? 373   /   F   B   ģ  ** 302 131
             030c    7b6b    291a    3f80    2ffb    4246    a3c4    cdc2
0000060    Y   ' 261 200   Q 331   a 276 276 350 001   s   ~ 222 262 175
             2759    80b1    d951    be61    e8be    7301    927e    dcb2
0000100    }   6 226 231 367   d 200   {   2   + 211 337 342 020   O 022
             367d    9996    64f7    7b80    2b32    df89    10e2    f14f
0000120  022 343 035 246   D 211   m   ~ 003 326   O 235 030 236  \0  \0
             e312    a61d    8944    7e6d    d603    9d4f    9e18    0000
0000140   \0
             0000
```

**UPDATE**

I also tried to use FileInputStream. Following gives same error

```
      GZIPInputStream strm = new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(tmpFileName));
```

Comment: I want to add that if this is a sophisticated program and the file is user-selected, you may want to catch the exception and alert the user (the program should continue running, allowing the user to select another file). But I suppose this is a simple one-time use program.

Comment: @ADTC  This is a server app and any error such as this one are caught, logged, and available for alerting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `fcontents` contains your gzipped data it should be a `byte[]` and not a `String`?

I recommend using [IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) for reading the file into a byte array as reading it into a string will most likely corrupt your data.

Comment: same error occurred when I tried getBytes("ISO-8859-1")  . The input was a simple ascii text file. in any case i'll add hex dump

Comment: Should `fcontents` contain the gzipped or the plain data? In the first case, do not read it it as String but directly as `byte[]` using IOUtils. Otherwise you would use a GZipOutputStream to convert the plain data to gzip

Comment: fcontents is directly read from a .gz file o it is gzipped data.

Comment: Than reading it as String will corrupt the data read. Use IOUtils or if you cannot use a third party library read it using FileInputStream and not BufferedReader

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46203/discussion-between-ooxi-and-javadba)

Comment: Finally I used this                      GZIPInputStream strm = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(dfs.open(f.getPath()))));